# How to set custom ASMX webservice URL in Visual WebParts

Tags: 2010, web-services

I have developed a custom ASMX webservice for integration with Oracle EBS database and we have UAT and Production environments. Ive have deployed the webservice on both places and working on UAT to test the visual webparts. Once the webpart is tested and approved i will move them to production.

My URLS for both environment.

**UAT**
http://uat.mydomain.com and service is http://uat.mydomain.com:6000/MyWebSvc.asmx

**Production**
http://portal.mydomain.com and service is http://portal.mydomain.com:6000/MyWebSvc.asmx

How can I make my code work on both places without changing the service URLS inside the code for uat to production and vise versa...guide me according to the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Settings Manager from Microsoft's patterns and practices group.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx